Using PipeStream to transfer response stream for logging without loosing streaming effect for endpoints
I have an endpoint which streams List as IAsyncEnumerable in the response and so when consumed on the browser, the response loads with a streaming effect as the data is written to the response stream.
Now, I also have a cross cutting middleware which aims to log every Api request and response body streams to azure blob.
My issue is that with this middleware enabled, although I get the output, but I lose the streaming effect of the endpoint when used on UI, but when disabled, I can see the streaming effect (data shown in chunks as available on stream) on the browser UI when the Api is requested. .
Below is the middleware code
public class LogRequestResponseInBlobMiddleware
{
    private const string REQUEST_RESPONSE_BLOB_FILE_PATH = "Blob/req-resp-logs";
    public const string LOGGING_KEY = "Identifier_Key";

    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
  
    private readonly IRequestResponseLogEntityBlobData _requestResponseLogEntityBlobData;
   
    public LogLLMRequestResponseInBlobMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ApiConfigurationBase apiConfigurationBase, IRequestResponseLogEntityBlobData requestResponseLogEntityBlob, IBoldContextPropertiesAccessor boldContextPropertiesAccessor, IBoldLogger boldLogger, IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnv)
    {
        _next = next;       
        _requestResponseLogEntityBlobData = requestResponseLogEntityBlob;      
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {  
            //Logging model structure
            LLMRequestResponsesLog logRequestResponseBlobModel = new LLMRequestResponsesLog()
            {                   
                EndpointName =context?.Request.Path.Value,
                LogIdentifierKey=LOGGING_KEY,
                RequestStartAt = DateTime.Now,
                Environment = _hostingEnv.EnvironmentName
            };
            
            //Request                
            var originalRequestStream = context.Request.Body;
          

            var requestMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            await context.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(requestMemoryStream);
            requestMemoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            context.Request.Body = requestMemoryStream;

            //Response
            var originalResponseStream = context.Response.Body;
            var respMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            context.Response.Body = respMemoryStream;

            //call next middleware in line
            await _next(context);

            //copy streams back to earlier ones
            context.Request.Body = originalRequestStream;
            if (respMemoryStream.Length > 0 && originalResponseStream.CanWrite)
            {
                respMemoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                await respMemoryStream.CopyToAsync(originalResponseStream);
            }

            if (context.Response.StatusCode != StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)
            {
             
               // var openAIRequestResponses = context.Items["someKey"] as LLMRequestResponseLogBlobModel;

                if (requestMemoryStream.Position != 0)
                {
                    requestMemoryStream.Position = 0;
                }
                if (respMemoryStream.Position != 0)
                {
                    respMemoryStream.Position = 0;
                }

                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(requestMemoryStream);
                var llmApiRequest = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();

                streamReader = new StreamReader(respMemoryStream);
                var llmApiResponse = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();

                //preparing the structure in which log has to be written
                logRequestResponseBlobModel.APIRequest = llmApiRequest;
                logRequestResponseBlobModel.APIResponse = llmApiResponse;
                logRequestResponseBlobModel.ResponseStatusCode = context.Response.StatusCode;
               

                try
                {                       
                    string appendblobName = GetNewAppendBlobNameForCurrentHour(); 
                 
                    //logging the structure to Azure Append Blob
                    await _requestResponseLogEntityBlobData.AddToAppendBlobAsync(appendblobName, logRequestResponseBlobModel.GetStream());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (ex is RequestFailedException requestFailedException)
                    {
                        // current blob has reached the maximum allowed block size i.e. it has been appended more than 50K times
                        if (requestFailedException.ErrorCode.Contains("BlockCountExceedsLimit"))
                        {
                           //log exception
                        }
                        else
                        {                                
                            //log exception
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //log exception
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    streamReader.Dispose();

                    // remove the item from http context
                    context.Items.Remove("someKey");
                }
            }

            //gracefully dispose            
            requestMemoryStream.Dispose();
            respMemoryStream.Dispose();        

    }
}


On analysis, I found that in the middlware,both the request and response streams are buffered in memory before passing them along to context and so might be I am loosing the streaming effect. Furthermore, through this  & this  approach, it seemed to me using PipeStreams i.e. AnonymousPipeServerStream & AnonymousPipeClientStream as in this IPC  example should be my ways as this would allow the bytes generated by the producer or the endpoint response to be transferred for logging to blob in background , while show response on UI as progressive stream.
So, I created AnonymousPipeServerStream object for copy api context response body stream, and tried to set it to context.Response.Body by reading bytes from AnonymousPipeClientStream.
However, while implementation, I am getting struck in some deadlock, and my middleware is crashing the web api.
Below is the new implementation
public class LogRequestResponseInBlobMiddleware
    {
        private const string REQUEST_RESPONSE_BLOB_FILE_PATH = "Blob/req-resp-logs";
        public const string LOGGING_KEY = "Identifier_Key";

        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    
        private readonly IRequestResponseLogEntityBlobData _requestResponseLogEntityBlobData;
    
        public LogLLMRequestResponseInBlobMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ApiConfigurationBase apiConfigurationBase, IRequestResponseLogEntityBlobData requestResponseLogEntityBlob, IBoldContextPropertiesAccessor boldContextPropertiesAccessor, IBoldLogger boldLogger, IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnv)
        {
            _next = next;       
            _requestResponseLogEntityBlobData = requestResponseLogEntityBlob;      
        }
        
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {           

            //add request start time to compute endpoint responseTime while saving all metrics - show it over grafana
            if (context is not null)
            {
                context.Items.TryAdd("EndpointRequestStartAt", DateTime.UtcNow);
            }

          
                //Logging model structure
                LLMRequestResponsesLog logRequestResponseBlobModel = new LLMRequestResponsesLog()
                {                   
                    EndpointName =context?.Request.Path.Value,
                    LogIdentifierKey=LOGGING_KEY,
                    RequestStartAt = DateTime.Now,
                    Environment = _hostingEnv.EnvironmentName
                };
                
                //Request                
                var originalRequestStream = context.Request.Body;
                

                var requestMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                await context.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(requestMemoryStream);
                requestMemoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                context.Request.Body = requestMemoryStream;

                //Response
                using var pipeResponseServerStream = new AnonymousPipeServerStream(PipeDirection.Out);
                using var pipeResponseClientStream = new AnonymousPipeClientStream(PipeDirection.In, pipeResponseServerStream.GetClientHandleAsString());

                var originalResponseStream = context.Response.Body;                
                context.Response.Body = pipeResponseServerStream;

              
                //call next middleware in line
                await _next(context);

                //copy streams back to earlier ones
                context.Request.Body = originalRequestStream;

                // getting struck in some deadlock in below line while copying the response published by pipeResponseServerStream
                await pipeResponseClientStream.CopyToAsync(originalResponseStream).ConfigureAwait(false);


   // same code as above middleware
              
                          //gracefully dispose            
                requestMemoryStream.Dispose();
                //respMemoryStream.Dispose();
           

        }
    }

It would be great if somebody could help me understand why am I facing deadlock while accessing the response client stream.  I am also not sure using AnonymousPipeServerStream & AnonymousPipeClirnyStream for this kind of in-process communication is valid option or not .
